# What do you think the fair price of this stock is based on these summarized financial statements?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I have been trying to make a valuation by reading the financial statements, but I believe I am just guessing. I have an idea, but I do not understand completely. Can I get a valuation and a short explanation as to how the valuation is came up with? The reference i'm trying to understand is:

Annual:[image: Annual]

Quarterly: [image: Quarterly]

Comment: You can do a comparables or DCF valuation analysis using the financial statements, although, you will need more thorough financial statements then the ones provided in the link.

Comment: @NuWin the only information I have are those though. How can I come up on which stock to invest to given those information?

Comment: Valuations are a guesstimate at best, they are usually based on biased assumptions and can vary greatly from one analyst to the next. Technical analysis of price action is the only analysis based on unbiased facts - the price.

Comment: @Victor I guess intrinsic value of a stock is more of the approach I guess and is just arbitrary. I'm just lost in technical analysis because all the stock that I bought that "broke out" just got slammed dunked at the end of the day and I just lose money. I do cut my losses but I cut more than I gain. What worked for you?

Comment: Like if you look at the stock in this main post you'll see it's a 17% down just today after a breakout and you won't know if that's consolidation or not unless you know the story why it broke out. And according to a stock broker I met recently, the breakout was due to an increase in profits recently and they valuated the company's market value to be around 2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is a link question. All the pertinent data is on a linked website that may not be available in the future. Once tomorrows data is added into the  site the question and answers may be outdated.

Comment: Here is the best estimate of the value of this stock:

https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/FOOD:PM

No, you're not better at valuing stock than the stock market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With only a single financial statement showing two periods, fundamental analysis is difficult. You are going to have to make a LOT of assumptions to determine a fair price. Is the cash flow in the period normal or abnormal? Will the growth in cash flow in that period be sustainable?  What factors might hinder future growth? Are there a lot of non-cash activities that would help or hurt the company in the long run?

Another method is by comparing *multiples*. Look at ratios such as price/earnings (P/E), price/sales, and price/book to see if the stock *appears* to be "undervalued" relative to other companies in the same market. You still need to be cautious, though, since the denominator in these ratios could be unsustainable (earnings or sales could be inflated due to uncommon activity) or there are other factors not accounted for in these ratios to justify the high or low price.

> I believe I am just guessing

You are - but so is everyone else. Bottom line - with only that much information, your guess is as good as anyone else's

Comment: Thanks this is a good start to look into fundamental analysis. I'm thinking of creating a checklist to look into for evaluating a company that can give me a general idea of the overall health of a company using fundamental analysis. Then further manage risk by combining with technical and statistical analysis. (Automated & holistic screening algorithms on all stocks in database based on momentum, volume, trend intensity, RSI, and etc. -> fundamental & technical analysis of stock/market health -> stock selection & re-balancing period)

Answer (score -4):

Stocks are worth nothing, zero, until someone places a **Bid**.

(Things like "analysis documents" from brokerages and "spreadsheets" from corporations, are: advertising. They are marketing materials.)

The stock is worth zero because it has no bids.

Comment: But then i'm interested in finding out on which stock would most likely go up in value. Technical analysis alone is not enough for me. I want to further lessen my risk by buying stocks that are good but undervalued

Comment: Unfortunately and sadly you cannot lessen your risk.  Of the huge, huge number of full-time professionals who manage trading accounts (funds, hedge funds, traders .. etc etc etc) the vast majority of them lose money year after year. If there was a way to "lessen risk" they would do it.

Comment: There are risks that cant be avoided for sure. But diversifying into a portfolio and choosing good stocks that are good both technically and fundamentally can probably give you a higher chance of success I believe because they will be more robust thus less risk. So i'm trying to understand whether the market value of the stock right now is overvalued or undervalued by trying to determine the intrinsic value of the stock. If it's undervalued and with good potential in the future and good management of the company then probability of it going up is higher

Comment: @Pherdindy Yes, there are stocks that are "more likely" to be "safer" than some others (think blue-chip vs. .COM-boom-bandwagoners) (but there are no guarantees (think Enron, Pan Am)). What you will very rarely find are over- or under-valued stock. The "current price" (using the term slightly loosely) will have been reached by people and institutions far more versed in reading balance sheets, following company, corporate and political news (plus a degree of gut feeling and guesswork), making trades far larger than you ever will. Any  "probability of going up" will already be in the price.

Comment: @TripleHound so for single persons like me what can you suggest that I do besides pray for the best? I believe the assumption of technical analysis is that everything is already accounted for in the price. So if that's the case I shouldn't bother with fundamentals at all? If it's just a pointless act of effort to try to learn the value of a company

Comment: hi @Pherdindy , Of the huge, huge number of full-time professionals who manage trading accounts (funds, hedge funds, traders .. etc etc etc) **the vast majority of them lose money year after year**. Your best bet is an index fund, it seems in the long run it will go up.  (Of course, very often it goes way down for 10 or 20 years.)

Comment: @Fattie Yes I do know how hard to market is at this point. But I am interested in knowing the ways of how to increase my chances in the market. For instance, if I know the support is very heavy and strong at a certain point and I know the company is undervalued, then I can enter because my chances are good. I need the calculations specifically. I bought a stock that is being bought by a large institution and has been holding support no matter who sold at him worth hundreds of millions. I am likely to earn money if I buy at the same levels as him when he is accumulating

Comment: "But I am interested in knowing the ways of how to increase my chances in the market. "  There is honestly no way.   "I know the company is undervalued"  there is absolutely no way to know this.  If there was traders and funds would make money in the markets.   "I need the calculations specifically"  it is utterly unknown how to "value" a company.  It is literally equivalent to saying "guess the future price".  If anyone could do this they would be rich.  If anyone could time travel, thet would just win the lottery.

Comment: Most people say "spread out" diversify to reduce risk.  The best bet seems to be just buying an index fund.

Comment: Notice people have downvoted this answer, which says it can't be done.  But of course, **you won't see any answers explaining how it can be done**.   Because it can't be done.

Comment: People say spread out to diversify as to protect from the risk that can't be avoided. Such as lawsuits, calamities, and etc. Logically, I think it lessens risk no matter how you look at it. Buying at support is similar to applying principles of physics when the walls are harder, then the chances of it breaking is much less it's a universal truth. I am just interested in finding out other ways to cross check and if everything looks good then i'll be more likely to enter. I'm just saying trying to determine the value of something is better than being blindfolded, but I know there's uncertainty.

Comment: Financial statements are facts as well unless rigged or the data is not accurate. It represents actual happenings. That's why I believe knowing how to use those information can further lessen risk even if the information is late from the market price. Because the more information you know the more better decisions you can make. And i'm just interested in how people normally evaluate companies because I don't know anything :/

Comment: True, the financial statements are of course facts.  But earnings and worth have no connection to stock market prices.  "And i'm just interested in how people normally evaluate companies"  that's perfectly reasonable; but it would be dangerous to use it to trade as it doesn't work  :)

Comment: I get what you mean because stock price is just supply and demand really and there are millions of factors out there and the statements despite being good might not translate to results. That's why I never really considered fundamental analysis before, but i'm interested in hearing the take of other people especially fundamental analysts because I want widen my perspective maybe it might make sense and be practical.

Comment: Our countries richest fund manager--similary to Warren writes so many macro economic articles. He probably understands the economics happening around the country. For 20 years his fund has outperformed and he's a billionaire. Similarly to warren and many investors out there they prefer to look at the intrinsic value of the stock and i'm trying to understand it. https://www.philstar.com/business/2016/03/13/1562629/happy-7th-birthday-bull-market This is how he analyzes things and it works.

Comment: I completely understand and you should look in to what those two guys have to say.  the trouble with the 1 or 2 examples (on Earth) of guys who "made a lot of money from saying they are fundamentalists" ..  it's not rational that only "2" people have ever been able to do this, it's probably just luck of the crowd. ("there had to be one or two") Secondly Buffet basically made "2 or 3 really good calls" (like "insurance will do well"). That's it really. Consider say pro Poker. Observably, unarguably and statistically, you can be "good" at it and "good" players win money. Not the case w/ trading.

Comment: (Anyway as you say you wish to hear about how those two dudes proceed - and fair enough.)

Comment: @Fattie thanks the market is hard with a lot of people saying what works and doesn't i'm just experimenting maybe i'll understand the market more and it will work for me